# Python - Parse Data from JS File (Twitter Archive)

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to parse my Twitter Archive Data. 
The data in my Contact list is as follows:

```
    window.YTD.contact.part0 = [ {
  "contact" : {
    "emails" : [ "mail@gmail.com" ],
    "phoneNumbers" : [ ]
  }
}, {
  "contact" : {
    "emails" : [ "mail@gmail.com" ],
    "phoneNumbers" : [ ]
  }
}, {
  "contact" : {
    "emails" : [ "mail@gmail.com" ],
    "phoneNumbers" : [ ]
  }
}, {
  "contact" : {
    "emails" : [ ],
    "phoneNumbers" : [ "+1234" ]
  }
}
```

And I want to parse this data like this:

```
Contact 1:
Email: Email here.
Phone Number: Phonenumber here.
```

File type: JS.
I tried to parse it using the json library in Python, but I couldn't. Could you help? Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to print that info?

Comment: @rusu_ro1 I want to print regularly and readily. As I mentioned in the last part of the article.

Comment: What you tried so far, add your code in the question too. then you can get better suggestions.

Comment: Please post what you've tried so far. What code are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can store this is in a variable let's say data. Than,

```
for d in data:    
    print(d['contact']['emails'])
    print(d['contact']['phoneNumbers'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//list 'data' stores contact list
for current in range(len(data)):
 contact = dict(data[current]['contact'])
 print('Contact '+ (str)(current + 1) + ':')
 if( len(contact['emails']) > 0):
    print('Email:' + contact['emails'][0])
 else:
    print('Email:')    
 if(len(contact['phoneNumbers']) > 0):
    print('Phone Number:' + contact['phoneNumbers'][0])
 else:
    print('Phone Number:')
```